# Why are features showing up near Malaysia when using the Michigan State Plan South coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system, fme-form, cad

I am using FME to write in shapefile and then read them to dwg's. The shapefiles have are assigned the Michigan South coordinate system, but show up near Malaysia when translated to CAD. What am I missing? The same thing is happening when using the Michigan Central system as well.

Comment: Please provide some of the original data used to create the shapefile.

Comment: The shapefiles I am converting to dwg were downloaded from an open data portal.

Comment: Please post a link to the shapefiles. Or a DropBox link to the files.

Comment: https://gis-michigan.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/lake-polygons/explore?location=44.837780%2C-86.417800%2C7.68

Comment: It looks like you have a coordinate system problem, see if any of the suggestions at https://ihatecoordinatesystems.com/ help.

Answer (score 1):

The first possible issue is that you don't have a method of storing the coordinate system defined on the AutoCAD writer. To fix that issue, carry out these steps:

Look in the Navigator window for the writer advanced parameter "Coordinate System Storage" and double-click it.

[image]

In the parameters dialog that opens, locate the same parameter and click the [...] button to open it up for edits:

[image]

Now pick which of the methods you want to use to store the information:

[image]

Even setting that up, if I use Internal Storage I get a warning:

```
AutoCAD Writer: Coordinate system '_LL-WGS84_0' cannot be stored using native storage, continuing
```

If you get the same message, then either set the storage to Internal WKT, or set the output coordinate system to be simply LL84.

That should solve the problem for you.